# How to store and retrieve an undefined guid with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, guid

My chrome extension reads an RSS feed that is updated quite often with new posts. What I want to do is assign every guid to an array that holds and then helps determine whether or not each post is new, and so ought to be passed on (as a notification to me).

```
    $.get('rss-feed', function(data) {
    var $xml = $(data);
    $xml.find("item").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            item = {
                title: $this.find("title").text(),
                link: $this.find("link").text(),
                description: $this.find("description").text(),
                pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                guid: $this.find("guid").text()
        }
```

The guid is then assigned to a variable:

```
    var latestID = item.guid.slice(-8);
```

This is where the problem takes place. The very same post keeps being posted as a new one. Is it because it has an undefined value?

```
    if (latestID == ids[0]) {

    } else if (latestID != ids[0]) {

        var firstNotification = {
            type: "basic",
            title: jobType[0] + ": " + jobWords[1] + " words",
            iconUrl: "icon48.png",
            message: jobPay[0] + "\nID: " + latestID + " Date: " + item.pubDate.slice(17,25),
            requireInteraction: true,
            buttons: [{
                    title: "Go to site!"
                }],
        };

        latestID = ids[0];
    }
```

Comment: Corrected indentation of code and added the missing closing bracket `}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage to save the value locally and check

```
window.localStorage.setItem("somename",item.guid.slice(-8));
```

Then you can retrieve wherever you want using,

```
var prevId = window.localStorage.getItem("somename");
```

You can compare now

Comment: Using localStorage seems a bit over the top in this context. Don't you think it's possible to pull it off just with conditionals and storing them right away in an array?

Comment: You have used .each function, are you assigning the value in latestID inside the .each function or outside?

Comment: Yes, everything runs inside it. Do you think that's the issue?

Comment: yes that is the issue always it will assign the last value